# What is the correct way to generate a CSV file in Django, Django REST Framework and send it as a streaming response from a POST request?

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-rest-framework, streaming

Generate CSV file using POST request

I try to achieve csv download using POST request by below code but not able to get file response it is returning normal response. What will be the valid approach to achieve streaming file response using POST request?

```
import csv
from django.http import StreamingHttpResponse
from rest_framework.decorators import api_view

def generate_csv_data():
    # Generate your CSV data here
    csv_data = [
        ['Name', 'Email'],
        ['John Doe', 'john.doe@example.com'],
        ['Jane Smith', 'jane.smith@example.com']
    ]

    # Yield each row of CSV data
    for row in csv_data:
        yield ','.join(row) + '\n'

@api_view(['POST'])
def download_csv(request):
    response = StreamingHttpResponse(generate_csv_data(), content_type='text/csv')
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="data.csv"'
    return response
```